# Use async await or task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

You have built a complex calculation algorithm. It takes quite some time to complete and you want to make sure that your application remains responsive. What do you do?

- A. Use async/await.
- B. Run the code synchronously.
- C. Use Task.Run.
- D. Use a BackgroundWorker.

The answer is C. However, can someone please explain why A) is incorrect? Because the question does not say that the complex algorithm is CPU bound. If it was CPU bound, then we will have to use Tasks (a reasoning I don't understand very well too, though I know that tasks  do help cause the current thread to get suspended until they complete). Additionally, please explain how to decide when to use async/await, and use Tasks.

Comment: False dichotomy; the answer is both A and C. Note that on ASP.NET, the answer is B.

Answer (score 3):

> What do you do?
>
> A. Use async/await.
>
> B. Run the code synchronously.
>
> C. Use Task.Run.
>
> D. Use a BackgroundWorker.

The `async/await` feature in C# 5.0 was implemented in order to make asynchronous code "as easy" as writing synchronous code. If you look into WinAPI, you'll see that almost all async endpoints expose a fully async api, meaning [*there is no thread*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). Looking further you'll notice that those same endpoints are doing [*I/O bound*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound) operations.

Assuming your algorithm is [*CPU bound*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_bound), and is written in a manner which allows effective computation across multiple processors (for example, your algorithm doesn't have any shared state which needs synchronization), you can take advantage of the [*Task Parallel Library*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) introduced in .NET 4.0. The TPL provides an abstraction over the ThreadPool, which in turn attempts to offload work evenly in a multiprocessor environment.

The `await` keyword can be used on any *awaitable* object, meaning that object implements the `GetAwaiter` method. You would want to use `await` when you are using an awaitable and want execution to resume when that awaitable is done doing its work. A `Task` implements the awaitable pattern and is used to describe a unit of work which will be completed in the future. You can use `Task.Run` and `await`, when you want to offload a unit of work on a worker thread and you want to **return control to the calling method until that work is done**.

Another way of dispatching CPU bound work across multiple processors is to use the [`Parallel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx) class which exposes `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach`.

On a side note, a `BackgroundWorker` can also be used to offload work on a background thread, if thats what the person asking the question was after. It is *recommended* to use the TPL since .NET 4.0 was released.

To conclude, using the Task Parallel Library is the recommended way to offload work to background threads. You may use them in combination with the `Parallel` library to maximize the parallelism of your algorithm. After doing so, **test your code** to make sure the overhead of using multiple threads doesn't outweigh the time it takes to run your algo synchronously.

**Edit**

As Stephan mentioned in the comment, you may combine both `Parallel.ForEach` and `Task.Run` to offload a parallel loop inside a background thread:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(.. //Loop here));
```

Comment: It can also be useful to combine approaches: `await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(...))` will do parallel work on background threads that the UI treats asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose "calculation" implies CPU bound algorithm in the absence of other information. If the algorithm is IO bound async/await is not only acceptable but the correct answer.

Comment: The thing is, even if you use `Task.Run()` you'd still have to `async\await` it for your UI to remain responsive. Right ?

Comment: That's true. Of course you can go for a Dispatcher approach.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov, if you're using `Task.Run`, the delegate passed to it will likely execute on a thread other than the UI thread, so *your UI will remain responsive* in any case where you don't block on the task's completion via `Wait()` or `Result`. How you choose to handle task's completion and communicate with the thread that called `Task.Run` in the first place, however, is up to you: you can use `await`, or you can use task continuations with the appropriate `TaskScheduler`, or you can explicitly capture the original SynchronizationContext and post back to it from within your delegate,

Comment: (cont'd) or you can use `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Control.Invoke`, or you can roll your own AsyncEnumerator (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx). My point is, there's about a million ways to do it, and `async/await` just happens to be one of them, even if it is the first thing that comes to everyone's mind (which is quite understandable).

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Sure, you're 100% right, I agree (even though you'r being a bit pedantic), but the fact that the question is garbage still remains (IMHO).

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov, agreed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question assumes you have an algorithm that has been programmed synchronously. The question mentions that it is a 'calculation' which vaguely implies that it is CPU-bound. It also very vaguely implies that the algorithm is written synchronously. E.g:

```
public int CalculateStuff() {
     ....
}
```

What I would consider is creating an asynchronous counterpart to this method:

```
public async Task<int> CalculateStuffAsync() {
      return await Task.Run(() => CalculateStuff());
}
```

Then in your user interface:

```
LoadingIndicator.IsEnabled = true;
ResultTextBox.Text = await CalculateStuffAsync();
LoadingIndicator.IsEnabled = false;
```

Hence the correct answer would probably be both A and C. In any case the question is too vague to draw any solid conclusion.

Comment: *Technically*, you can also use a `BackgroundWorker` ... Sure it's not the best approach (these days), but that's how we use to roll :P Basically I'm saying, this exam question is crap.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov agree, all except B are technically valid

Comment: @BasBrekelmans, providing public `xxxAsync` wrappers for CPU-bound work is poor design. It's not like the caller can't wrap `CalculateStuff` in `Task.Run` if it needs to. Also consider the following: `CalculateStuffAsync().Wait()`. Without `ConfigureAwait(false)` you've just introduced a deadlock bug that wasn't there until you wrote your `async` method, for pretty much zero benefit.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Why would that introduce a deadlock ? I thought `ConfigureAwait(false)` configures the execution to continue on a context that wasn't necessary the one that it was started on ? If anything that WOULD create a deadlock ? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov, don't take my word for it. Run your bit of code in an application which installs a non-null `SynchronizationContext` (i.e. Windows Forms/WPF) and see what happens. This is due to the fact that your `await` needs to transition to the original `SynchronizationContext` before the result of the async operation can be returned. If you block the thread via `Task.Wait`, that transition will never occur because the thread will be busy waiting for the task (which will never complete). Checkmate. Take out `async/await` and just return the task directly, and it's solved.

Comment: (or use `ConfigureAwait(false)` obviously)

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Thanks for taking the time to explain, and yeah, it makes sense now.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov, no problem; and please accept my apologies for incorrectly addressing my reply. I confused you for Bas Brekelmans when I wrote it.